# android - Most effective way to inconspicuously waste battery

Tags: android, background-process, battery, batterylevel

I was wondering, what is the best way to inconspicuously waste battery?

`Vibration` - very conspicuous.
`Brightess` - conspicuous, only drains battery well when the screen is turned on.
`Background data` - do random things with background data, such as loading a map and constantly refreshing it in the background. Seems like a good, inconspicuous way.

My question is: What is the most effective and inconspicuous way to drain the user's battery? Currently, I feel that something like the `Background data` thing would be the best, but is there any very good way that I did not think of?

Thank you!

**Information:** I do not actually plan on using this in an application. I am just curious.

Comment: OK, I'll bite: why?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why would you want to do this?

Comment: Am not sure, but most of my battery usage is the display screen.

Comment: I believe the most "inconspicuous" way would be to give the CPU complex problems to solve. That way you don't have to do anything the user might notice.

Comment: I sincerely hope you never release an app to the Play Store.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say your best bet is to continually ensure that 'Location/GPS', 'Mobile Data' and 'Wi-Fi' are all constantly turned on. That'd do the trick and waste the battery quick enough on a mobile.

However I must say that I am very intrigued as to why you'd want to waste a user's battery and not the opposite, save their battery! :O

Comment: @MoshErsan Yes they can both be turned on at the same time. It just means that maximum battery will be wasted as the mobile will try and connect to mobile data all the time to at least secure a connection as well as scan for a Wi-Fi connection continually as that is its preferred connection type (due to it usually being stronger).

Comment: @edwoollard, I will try to use this and see how effective this is. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkusWillson Sure thing. Let me know how testing goes.

Answer (score 3):

The most easy, no coding way to do that is to create a wakelock!

But battery statistics still will blame you for doing that. That wakelock can live in a sticky service being triggered by different "Broadcasts".

Of course it is a very bad idea for such an app.

Useless WakeLocks are always battery drains that can be hardly traced by the developers.